# Join AMAZON.DATE and AMAZON.TIME into sql DATETIME in python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, datetime, aws-lambda

I have a `python` code which gets following two parameters: `AMAZON.DATE` and `AMAZON.TIME` (format definition [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#numbers-dates-and-times)):

```
import pymysql

def func(date, start_time):
    conn = pymysql.connect(hostname, user=username,
                               passwd=password, db=database, connect_timeout=5)



    cur = conn.cursor()
    # SQL statement here
```

Now what I want to do is join these two date and time types and insert them as a sql `DATETIME` type. So the `insert` statement should be like - `INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (date_time);`. What I am having difficulty in is joining the two `Amazon types` and forming `sql DATETIME` type. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to convert AMAZON.DATE and AMAZON.TIME into datetime objects and then simply use

```
 datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(2011, 01, 01), datetime.time(10, 23))
```

For example -

```
 import datetime
 date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-06-07T', '%Y-%M-%dT').date()
 time_object = datetime.datetime.strptime('04:00','%H:%M').time()
 date_obj_final = datetime.datetime.combine(date_object, time_object)

#output
2015-01-07
04:00:00
2015-01-07 04:00:00
```

Let me know,if it works !

Comment: so `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(date), datetime.time(start_time))` is the correct syntax? date is AMAZON.DATE and start_time is AMAZON.TIME.

Comment: @user2966197 , if you find this answer useful please marked it , thanks